# How to get specific data from response in http

Tags: java, android, webview, httprequest, httpurlconnection

hello I'm trying to make specific my own browser with my custom headers in web view
so I'm intercepting every request and handle it myself and getting response from
shouldInterceptRequest method

so some post requests need specific form data like websessionid and app id and user
and i dont know where can i get this forms

although the browser can handle this requests easily without any issues

Here is what browser put in form data

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryjmBjfkvn5nntGgAB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ts"

1661786169771
------WebKitFormBoundaryjmBjfkvn5nntGgAB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="q"

[{"user":"0","webSessionId":"epufaw:xfhn5k:8jkn3p","app_id":"412378670482","posts": 
[["falco:ods_web_batch",{"e":"{\"batch\":{\"1344\":{\"falco.event.jstl_migration\": 
{\"js.use_banzai.log\":[2,null],\"js.banzai.posting_event\": 
[2,null],\"js.event.write_to_queue\":[2,null]},\"falco.fabric.www.C3\": 
{\"js.use_banzai.log\":[2,null],\"js.banzai.post.log\": 
[2,null],\"planes.banzai.write_to_transport\":[3,null],\"js.event.write_to_queue\": 
[3,null],\"js.use_banzai.log_immediately\":[1,null],\"js.banzai.post.log_immediately\": 
[1,null]},\"falco.event.web_blue_time_spent_navigation\":{\"js.use_banzai.log_immediately\": 
[1,null],\"js.banzai.posting_event\":[1,null],\"js.event.write_to_queue\":[1,null]}},\"2231\": 
{\"ChannelManager\":{\"stateDelegate.exit.m.cleanup\": 
[1,null],\"stateDelegate.enter.m.cleanup\":[1,null]}},\"2966\":{\"mqtt_ws_client\": 
{\"219994525426954.protocol.debug.disconnect.internal\": 
[100,null],\"protocol.debug.disconnect.internal\": 
[100,null]}}}}","r":1,"d":"$^|AcYop9f0zQ7JJ5ZoEp8Vpbsxq7ok2SX-ewPFsyzr4OH1hlce-dQHRTvomrRSL-
```

i dont know how and where can i get this forms

any solution?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36918490

Comment: @blackapps thats not my question

Comment: Then please write better what you want. Especially now that you know that you were unclear.